# Event.target.matches() "Unresolved Function" warning in plain js

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, webstorm

I'm trying to detect change on the input before a form is submitted.
It works with normal keyboard input and autocomplete (1password).
The code below is producing an "Unresolved Function" warning in PhpStorm.
This doesn't actually produce any errors in Chrome, but it might in other browsers.

```js
let inputEvents = {}
function onInput(selector, callback) {
    inputEvents[selector] = callback;
}
document.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
    for (let selector in inputEvents) {
        if (event.target.**matches**(selector)) {
            inputEvents[selector](event.target);
        }
    }
});
```

I removed the warning by checking the event type for `InputEvent`.
However this isn't the best solution as I cannot work with normal Events which are returned by Autocomplete.

```js
let inputEvents = {}
function onInput(selector, callback) {
    inputEvents[selector] = callback;
}
document.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
    for (let selector in inputEvents) {
        if (event instanceof InputEvent && event.target.matches(selector)) {
            inputEvents[selector](event.target);
        }
    }
});
```

Is there any other work around so that I can use the matches function for both `InputEvent` and `Event` types without a warning?

`inputEvents` is an array of callbacks, and `event.target` is used as a parameter for the callback.

To use the code I basically call

```js
onInput("input[type='text']",function(e){ ///code });
```

Whenever the selector is found, the function/callback will be executed.
Similar to jQuery

```js
$(document).on('input', 'input:text', function() {});
```

but without all the other library code which slows down my website.

Comment: Please post your code as text and not images, also please refer [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: _"warning in phpstorm"_ - are you getting an _actual_ error, when this executes in the browser, as well? _"However this code no longer works with autocomplete with 1password due to the event not being an InputEvent."_ - autocomplete, 1password ... where do those suddenly come from? Can you give us a _proper_ explanation of what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: How does this actually work `inputEvents[selector](event.target);`?

Comment: inputEvents is an array of callbacks, and event.target is used as a parameter for the callback.

To use the code I basically call onInput("input",function(e){ ///code });

Comment: what version is your JS in your IDE? `Menu > PhpStorm> Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript` I think that is the path....

Comment: It says ECMAScript 6+